# JAVA - Printing user input into HTML

Tags: java, html, printwriter

I want to acquire user input using Java and print it in a `index.html` form. The user input is in an arraylist. By the look of the code, you can tell it will print the HTML from `#nbOfPieces` times. How can I print the individual items from the arraylist and only print out the html code once?

```
for (int i = 0;i < nbOfPieces ;i++ ) {
                pw.println(
                    "<html>\n" +
                            "<head>\n" +
                            "    <title>Maria Shop</title>\n" +
                            "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">\n" +
                            "</head>\n" +
                            "<body>\n" +
                            "<center>\n" +
                            "<section id=\"portfolio\">\n" +
                            "        <h1>MARIA TEST</h1>\n" +
                            "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
                            "            <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
                            "            </div>\n" +
                            "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
                            "                <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
                            "            </div>\n" +
                            "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
                            "                <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
                            "            </div>\n" +
                            "</section>\n" +
                            "</center>\n" +
                            "</body>\n" +
                            "</html>"
                );
            }
```

Comment: By printing the opening stanza (`html` to `center`) before the loop, and then printing the closing stanza after the loop (`center` to `html`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split what you will print in three as this:

```
pw.println(
   "<html>\n" +
    "<head>\n" +
    "    <title>Maria Shop</title>\n" +
    "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">\n" +
    "</head>\n" +
    "<body>\n" +
    "<center>\n" +
    "<section id=\"portfolio\">\n" +
    "        <h1>MARIA TEST</h1>"
);
//Repeated sectection
for (int i = 0;i < nbOfPieces ;i++ ) {
    pw.println(
        "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
        "            <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
        "            </div>\n" +
        "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
        "                <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
        "            </div>\n" +
        "            <div class=\"img-box\">\n" +
        "                <a href=" + links.get(i) + "><img src=\"./img/"+subImg.get(i)+"\" alt=\"CPU image\"></a>\n" +
        "            </div>"
    );
}
pw.println(
    "</section>\n" +
    "</center>\n" +
    "</body>\n" +
    "</html>"
);
```